# how do I display add filter otiopn to my additional multi filter menu? looking for javascript codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This works great in itself but I am looking for a filter that once an option is chosen would display another filter next to it and so on.

Here is my multi select code in html which uses bootstrap-select js and css...(bootstrap multiselect)

```
<div class="container" id="menu1" style="padding-top:75px;">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group row">
         <div class="col-md-2">
           <label>Multiple</label>
            <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="number2-multiple" title="Select a number" 
            data-hide-disabled="true" multiple data-actions-box="true">
               <option>option1</option>
               <option>option2</option>
               <option>option3</option>
               <option>option4</option>
             </select>

         </div>

      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried to so far?  Please do take the time to read the [tour] and [ask], you'll get a much better response if you ask an on-topic question.

Comment: are you using any JS library (React or Mithirl JS)  then this should be a piece of cake, if you wanna try plain js, you can add a onchange event handler and there iterate through form of div(with ID 'menu1') and can append new html accordingly

Comment: I am simply using bootstrap and I am really new to javascripting so I am completely lost.

Comment: Basically I am looking for a multi-select filter with images grid that will shuffle with the selections

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ With reference to your comment "_I am looking for a filter that once an option is chosen would display another filter next to it_ " Unfortunately this site is not for asking for someone to give you the code that you're looking for _ What SO contributors will do is look at the code you have tried and help you to resolve any issues you're having _ As already recommended by @freedomn-m you should take some time to visit the Help Center and specifically the section on Asking >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking